# Hibernate inconsistently generating duplicate primary keys

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring and Hibernate (hibernate-core 3.3.1.GA), and as a result of a web call, the code does a transaction with several inserts. Sometimes, one of the inserts fails with Hibernate saying `'Duplicate entry ... for key 'PRIMARY'`. I have not been able to identify any pattern on when this happens -- it may work for 4 - 5 requests, and then it fails, then works on retrying, and then may fail on the next request.

Below are the relevant parts of the code:

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<Object, Object> save(<params>) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    ...
    try {
            map = userHelper.save(<parameters>);
    ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown in the above part.

**UserHelper.save() method**

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public HashMap<String, Object> save(<parameters>) throws NumberParseException, IllegalArgumentException, HibernateException {
    ....
    userService.save(<parameters>);
    return save;
}
```

**UserService**

```
HBDao dao;

@Autowired
public UserService(org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    dao = new HBDao(sessionFactory);
}
...
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public HashMap<String, Object> save(<parameters>) throws NumberParseException {
    ...
    User user;
    // several lines to create User object
    dao.save(user);
    ...
    lookupService.saveUserConfigurations(user, userType, loginById);
    ...
    return response;
}
```

**HBDao**

This class wraps hibernate sessions.

```
public HBDao(SessionFactory sf) {
    this.sessionFactory = sf;
}

private Session getSession() {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

public void save(Object instance) {
    try {
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(instance);
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        throw re;
    }
}
```

`lookupService.saveUserConfigurations(user, userType, loginById)` call results in the below methods in `LookupRepository` class to be executed:

**LookupRepository**

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public LookupMapping save(LookupMapping configuration) {
    dao.save(configuration);
    return configuration;
}

public Collection<LookupMapping> saveAll(Collection<LookupMapping> configurations) {
    configurations.forEach(this::save);
    return configurations;
}
```

**LookupMapping**

```
@Entity
public class LookupMapping {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long configId;
    ...
}
```

**Hibernate Mapping for LookupMapping class**

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com...configuration.domain">
    <class name="LookupMapping" table="lookup_mapping" mutable="false">
        <id column="id" name="configId" type="long">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Hibernate config**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="sosFactory">
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        ...

        <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">com. ... .CustomDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ManagedSessionContext</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        ...
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Below are the lines from the log:

```
2018-05-04 10:24:51.321 7|13|60f566fa-4f85-11e8-ba9b-93dd5bbf4a00 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Duplicate entry '340932' for key 'PRIMARY'
2018-05-04 10:24:51.321 7|13|60f566fa-4f85-11e8-ba9b-93dd5bbf4a00 WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
2018-05-04 10:24:51.322 7|13|60f566fa-4f85-11e8-ba9b-93dd5bbf4a00 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027) [hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar:3.3.1.GA]
    at com.arl.mg.helpers.UserHelper.save(UserHelper.java:329) [classes/:?]
...
```

I'm working on a legacy codebase (so cannot upgrade Hibernate easily), and the code that I wrote are in `LookupRepository` class (and `LookupService` which is called in `UserService`).

The `Duplicate entry` error happens while persisting the `LookupMapping` objects. There are always two of this object being persisted, and when the error occurs, the duplicate ID is created same as the last entry. That is, if for the first request, IDs `999` and `1000` were inserted, and if the error occurs for the next request, the duplicate ID will be `1000` (and not 999).

Another, possibly important thing to note is that Hibernate shows this line:

```
org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager [] - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
```

This is all the info that I have so far, and I hope I've covered the relevant code as well. Any help will be much appreciated. Do let me know if I have to give more info.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the `@Entity` classes, that is `LookupMapping`.

Comment: What is the generation strategy for the Entity's key, if any?

Comment: You are running, probably, outside a transaction. You used `SUPPORTED` as a propagation level which basically means if there is a tx, use it else fine as well. It will not start/require a transaction. Next to that the `saveAll` call runs without a transaction as that internally calls the `save` method bypassing the (potential) transactional proxy. Next to that you are catching exception which you shouldn't be doing in the first place as that breaks proper tx management.

Comment: @Shadov - I've added the entity class.

Comment: @anchreg - strategy is GenerationType.IDENTITY. I've added the entity class to the description.

Comment: @M.Deinum But that method is called as part of the UserHelper.save() call, which has REQUIRES_NEW as the propagation. Won't this ensure that there's a transaction bound to the thread?
And, I had tried REQUIRES_NEW and NESTED as well for the saveAll method, but the behaviour does not change at all.

Comment: Then why even bother using `SUPPORTS`. Nonetheless you are still catching exceptions (although those shouldn't occur) which shouldn't be done. Add your hibernate configuration to your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum What's the reason the exceptions shouldn't be caught? I think I added it after I started seeing this error, to check if I can get more info on it somehow -- I'll remove it.

Comment: That breaks proper tx management, Spring must see the exception so that it can do a rollback. If that doesn't happen it will try to commit the transaction because everything went ok (because it doesn't see the exception).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170364/discussion-between-shyam-and-m-deinum).

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Weird to have that error with identity generation, try checking the current value of auto_increment on database and the id's in the table. And check if you are not manually assigning the id's before saving (not sure if hibernate is gonna report any error if id is manually set even tho it should be generated).

Comment: @Shadov I'm using MySQL. I checked the auto increment value and I'm not assigning ID's before saving. Everything looks fine.
And yes, it is weird. :/

Comment: Check the SQL generated by hibernate, if it contains insert to ID column.

Comment: It does not. @Shadov

Comment: I would remove the `@Transactional` annotation from the `UserHelper` class and the `propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS` from the service layer; moreover may you show your Spring + Hibernate config?

Answer (score 5):

The problem was with the ID generation strategy defined in the Hibernate mapping file.

The strategy was set as `increment`, which seems to work only when there are no other processes inserting to the table. In my case, it seems that sometimes there were previously open sessions, and new requests ended up inserting to the table simultaneously.

The solution was to change the strategy to `native`, which uses the underlying database's strategy to generate ID.

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com...configuration.domain">
    <class name="LookupMapping" table="lookup_mapping" mutable="false">
        <id column="id" name="configId" type="long">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 4):

I agree with response by @shyam  I would switch to some sequence generator.

But also have a look at this peace of code:

```
User user;
// several lines to create User object
dao.save(user);
...
lookupService.saveUserConfigurations(user, userType, loginById);
```

In this case you are sending `user` to `saveUserConfigurations` which is not managed, and within `saveUserConfigurations` you might calling `merge` method. This will cause additional insert statement. Consider refactoring your code to:

```
User user;
// several lines to create User object
// dao.save should return the stored value of user.
user = dao.save(user);
...
lookupService.saveUserConfigurations(user, userType, loginById);
```

With such constructions you will be using stored entity (i.e. managed by current hibernate's session). and have a look at all your code and prevent usage of not managed entities once those have been stored.